# SSIS Package - Execution Timed Out error

Tags: ssis

I have dozens of SSIS packages being executed on various schedules, all controlled via the SQL Agent. Sometimes I'll notice a job hasn't fired on its regular schedule and I'll check the History of the job. I'll then notice that recent executions of the job have failed with an error message that says, "Description: The operation failed because the execution timed out..."

I'm pretty certain that this is not related to the actual code inside the SSIS package because I have an error event handler set up, and an error is never generated from within the package itself. I would know this because I have the event handler set up to send me an email on any sort of error. I am not getting any emails from these packages.

The only thing I see is the History showing this timed out error. So, my question is this. What exactly is timing out, and why?

Comment: Maybe look in the SQL Server logs  and see if there is more info on this timeout

Comment: Sounds like this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/46c36455-01c2-422b-bf7f-47f950d6ec51/sql-server-2012-job-intermittently-unable-to-kickoff-or-start-ssis-2012-package-the-operation?forum=sqlintegrationservices what version of SQL Server and SSIS?

Comment: I suspect two things over here 1- Check for script task (if you have any) to identify if any variable is locked. 2 - Consider monitoring TempDb (you can check for contention & size of TempDb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was blocked because of the poor quality of my answers even though my answers were correct. But other people can still post something that is completely irrelevant to the question simply because they have "good" reputation. The problem here has nothing to do with tempdb.

At least please copy my answer if maybe it will help someone to solve their problem:

It's [SSIS].[catalog].[create_execution] procedure that is timing out trying to get app lock.
The best advice is probably not to schedule too many SSIS jobs at the same time. If you have a lot of jobs that all start let's say at 5PM then try scheduling them at 5:00:10PM, 5:00:20PM, 5:00:30PM etc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlblog/ssis-execution-time-out-error-when-using-ssisdb-stored-procedure-catalog-create_execution